# Not Only TV USB tuner not working

Tags: drivers, usb, hardware, tv-tuner

How can I install a [Not Only TV](http://www.notonlytv.net/) USB tuner on Ubuntu 12.04? Are there any drivers for it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/NotOnlyTV). This does not look very promising - so possibly there are no drivers.

Answer (score 0):

**Following this steps I did it work:**

**1. Open the shell and execute line per line:**

```
git clone git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git

git clone --depth=1 git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git

cd media_build

./build    

sudo make install  

gedit /etc/modprobe.d/LV3H.conf
```

**2. Add this line to the blank file:**

```
options cx88xx card=81 tuner=71
```

**3. Save it and close Gedit. In the shell execute:**

```
wget http://www.steventoth.net/linux/xc5000/HVR-12x0-14x0-17x0_1_25_25271_WHQL.zip

unzip -j HVR-12x0-14x0-17x0_1_25_25271_WHQL.zip Driver85/hcw85bda.sys

wget http://linuxtv.org/hg/v4l-dvb/raw-file/3919b17dc88e/linux/Documentation/video4linux/extract_xc3028.pl

perl extract_xc3028.pl

sudo cp xc3028-v27.fw /lib/firmware

modprobe cx88-dvb
```

**7. Reboot. Congratulations! You have your Me-TV (or like program) running and waiting to autodetect channels.**